Can mat-ripple be used in mat-table rows?
In Angular (with Material) version 17, I'm not being able to get the ripples working along with other mat-table features, such as sticky columns and rows (or even x-axis scrolling).
Here's the problem demonstrated in a few ways I tried to get it working.
Is it possible to get this to work? Is it just a situation that Angular Material isn't covering? I couldn't find an issue for this in the GitHub repo. Should an issue be created?
